# Excluding elemens via NOT IN Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I am trying to create a query in Symfony 2.3 which should exclude some elements based on the ID in another table, for example I have an SMS table, and a SMS_Deleted table, I need to exclude ids from SMS_Deleted from the query.

I have this first query to get the SMS deleted:

```
$sms_exceptions = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getEntityManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select(array('s.idClient'))
    ->from('AloBundle:SmsDeleted', 's')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

in `$sms_exceptions` I get all ids should be excluded from the SMS query. Then in the SMS Repository I have this:

```
public function findByClientArray($id_client, $sms_exceptions, $from, $to, $jtStartIndex, $jtPageSize)
    {
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

        return $this->getEntityManager('voipswitch')
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select(array('s.idClient, s.sentTime as date, s.toNumber as destiny, s.smsStatus as status, s.smsText as sms'))
        ->from('VoipswitchBundle:SmsOutbox', 's')
        ->where('s.idClient = :id_client AND s.sentTime >= :from AND s.sentTime <= :to')
        ->where($qb->expr()->notIn('s.idSms', $sms_exceptions))
        ->setParameter('id_client', $id_client)
        ->setParameter('from', new \DateTime($from))
        ->setParameter('to', new \DateTime($to))
        ->where($qb->expr()->notIn('s.idSms', $sms_exceptions))
        ->orderBy('s.sentTime', 'DESC')
        ->setFirstResult($jtStartIndex)
        ->setMaxResults($jtPageSize)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
    }
```

Any help please???

Thanks

Comment: notIn operator works slow.. I'd use single query (with joins) to get results..

Comment: The problem is the SMS_Deleted table is in a different database, I am using one EM for SMS and another SMS_Deleted in another EM. How would be the sintax for this case?

Comment: take a look at this [documentation page](http://www.doctrine-project.org/2009/06/19/cross-database-joins.html)

Comment: [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/fgj1R9aJask) is interesting also..

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $queryBuilder
    ->select(['f'])
    ->from('AcmeDemoBundle:FirstEntity', 'f')
    ->leftJoin('AcmeDemoBundle:SecondEntity', 's', 'WITH', 'f.sId = s.id')
    ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->isNull('s.id'))
    ...
    ...
```

or with association:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $queryBuilder
    ->select(['f'])
    ->from('AcmeDemoBundle:FirstEntity', 'f')
    ->leftJoin('f.secondEntity(ies)', 's')
    ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->isNull('s.id'))
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: The SecondEntity is in another database, so I am using two EntityManager, how would it be in this case?